# MBR: Restore Windows 7 bootloader on a Thinkpad

Tags: windows-7, bootloader, thinkpad, mbr

I previously uninstalled Fedora dual boot and now have the GNU Grub bootloader still hanging around. I have found instructions online on how to remove this but they all require the Windows 7 CD. I do not have one because I have a Thinkpad. Unfortunately, I cannot install Thinkpad's rescue and recovery without the original thinkpad BMGR bootloader installed. Are there any alternatives?

EDIT: After looking into this further, I believe I might need the Thinkpad bootloader rather than the one from a Windows 7 CD.

**EDIT2: Ultimately, I had to restore to factory settings, but that resolved the issue.**

Comment: [Obtaining the Win7 DVD](http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-do-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft) is not an issue, but the ThinkPad has a custom bootloader for Win7? Are you sure?

Comment: Can you make that edit an answer and mark it accepted, so this question becomes "solved"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I had to restore to factory settings, but that resolved the issue.